# why is bit manipulation not working for CSES Bit strings problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer-overflow

The problem states to print the number of bit strings possible of size n. Mathematically, the answer is just 2^n but because n can be from 1 to 10^6, the answer must be a data type of larger size. Here is my program:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using ll = long long;
using ull = unsigned long long;
const int MOD = (int)1e9 + 7;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << ((1ULL << n) % MOD);
}
```

I even tried using LL, ULL and I even tried making n ull or ll. But none of these methods work. Can someone explain why? isn't the range for ULL big enough?
In some solutions, I see a for loop where the answers is multiplied by 2 and mod MOD in each iteration of the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) ans = ans*2 % ((int)1e9 + 7)
```

Won't this give the wrong answer since if somewhere in one of the iterations of the loop, the answer goes above MOD, it will become the remainder of MOD and then again start multiplying by 2. Wouldn't the correct answer be to first FIND the answer and THEN mod it by MOD? Using the loop way, it will keep exponentiating the REMAINDER which I don't understand how it is the right answer.

Comment: Could you share a link to that problem, please?

Comment: "But none of these methods work." What doesn't work exactly? What is the expected result and what do you actually get?

Comment: Do you need a data type with 1 million bits (so capable of holding a number 2^(10^6))?

Comment: Link to problem: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1617/. @NotAProgrammer i tried making n a ULL and a LL (unsigned long long and long long) and I did 1ULL << n instead of 1<<n. I see now that there is no data type that has 10^6 bits which would be needed for this. But I don't see how exponentiating the remainder still gives the right answer. How can exponentiating a remainder give the same answer and if we actually did take (2^n) % MOD??

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, no, ULL is not big enough.

Recall an unsigned long long is usually 64 bits large, so there's no way you can shift 1 10^6 bits without overflow.

The solution to this problem is exponentiation by squaring and taking a modulo each step; using the property that a*a % mod = (a%mod) * (a%mod). This solves the problem in log(10^6) time.

Take a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exponential-squaring-fast-modulo-multiplication/

Comment: I see. But, as I mentioned in my question, wont each iteration just exponentiate the remainder? so if n = 255, technically the ans would be 2^(255) % MOD but in the iterative solution, you take mod way before you reach the answer and keep exponentiating the remainder (and this process would keep repeating). Can you explain how this is correct?

Comment: As I have mentioned, a*a % mod = (a%mod) * (a%mod). This is a basic principle in modular arithmetic. Therefore, you can spit 2^n into 2^(n/2) * 2(n/2). If you want more information you can look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27336/associativity-commutativity-and-distributivity-of-modulo-arithmetic